# Find non-sequential counters in log

Tags: command-line, bash, logging

I have a log like this:

```
Line 107758: [LOG] New acqusition CNT=48497 EPOCH=1516696452
Line 107767: [LOG] New acqusition CNT=48498 EPOCH=1516696453
Line 107776: [LOG] New acqusition CNT=48499 EPOCH=1516696454
Line 107785: [LOG] New acqusition CNT=48499 EPOCH=1516696455
Line 107794: [LOG] New acqusition CNT=48501 EPOCH=1516696456
Line 107803: [LOG] New acqusition CNT=48502 EPOCH=1516696457
Line 107812: [LOG] New acqusition CNT=48503 EPOCH=1516696458
```

with 15000+ lines.
I'm interested to print out lines with non-sequential values of CNT (i.e. 48499-48501).

I'm able to do this writing a software or a script. I wonder if there's a bash command to help with without doing it manually.

"Manually means":

1. parse a line and store the CNT value in a variable
2. parse line+1 and store the CNT value in another variable
3. compare both and check their values
4. if matched print out the values
5. copy value of line+1 into line variable
6. go ahead with next line

Comment: I think the word is `non-sequential`. And no, that sounds like a _very_ specific task (which can be done with two lines of awk) – I doubt anyone would bother writing _and publishing_ a dedicated program.

Comment: If you're interested in the same lines just use grep. Assuming they are increased every time ... also use grep for other cases? But with your description I guess they don't just gradually increase as time passes? You probably can do it in awk but I'm not sure how that would have to look.

Comment: @grawity I'm not asking anyone to writing a program for me. As said I'm able to do with. I was asking if there's a command line tool useful for log analysis. Thanks for the hint about the word, I'm going to edit the question.

Comment: @Seth Unfortunately, there's not guarantee about the EPOCH value (which increases only, of course) but may have any value - the same for Line value.